# Boostrap sass functions, (mix function in scss )?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

Inside of bootstrap-5 function scss files we can find a "**mix**" function, I dont find any about it on google.

where can I find documentation about it?

[image: function.scss screen capture]

Comment: It's a sass thing. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#mix

Answer (score 1):

Searching github and google gives this: [mix](https://github.com/sass/libsass/blob/288610acfaa797b44c1a58a18b2cbd2e03937498/src/fn_colors.cpp#L166) -> [colormix](https://github.com/sass/libsass/blob/288610acfaa797b44c1a58a18b2cbd2e03937498/src/fn_colors.cpp#L148).

And there is [javascript version of colormix](https://gist.github.com/jedfoster/7939513):

```cpp
    Color_RGBA* colormix(Context& ctx, SourceSpan& pstate, Color* color1, Color* color2, double weight) {
      Color_RGBA_Obj c1 = color1->toRGBA();
      Color_RGBA_Obj c2 = color2->toRGBA();
      double p = weight/100;
      double w = 2*p - 1;
      double a = c1->a() - c2->a();

      double w1 = (((w * a == -1) ? w : (w + a)/(1 + w*a)) + 1)/2.0;
      double w2 = 1 - w1;

      return SASS_MEMORY_NEW(Color_RGBA,
                             pstate,
                             Sass::round(w1*c1->r() + w2*c2->r(), ctx.c_options.precision),
                             Sass::round(w1*c1->g() + w2*c2->g(), ctx.c_options.precision),
                             Sass::round(w1*c1->b() + w2*c2->b(), ctx.c_options.precision),
                             c1->a()*p + c2->a()*(1-p));
    }
```

I suppose `precision` is `10` from:

```cpp
struct Sass_Inspect_Options {

  // Output style for the generated css code
  // A value from above SASS_STYLE_* constants
  enum Sass_Output_Style output_style;

  // Precision for fractional numbers
  int precision;

  // initialization list (constructor with defaults)
  Sass_Inspect_Options(Sass_Output_Style style = Sass::NESTED,
                       int precision = 10)
  : output_style(style), precision(precision)
  { }

};
```