# How to implement SASS color functions in raw CSS

Tags: css, function, sass, colors

SASS has functions which can compute a new color given some variables as input. Specifically, I'm using:

- https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color/#mix
- https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color/#lighten
- https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color/#darken

CSS now also has variables and some related builtin functionality like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter.

I also managed to implement `lighten`/`darken` by using `hsl(var(--my-hue), var(--my-saturation), calc(var(--my-lightness) + 10%))`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on whether it's possible to implement/hack `mix` in pure CSS (the [source code of mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502147/boostrap-sass-functions-mix-function-in-scss)) - maybe also using some representations like `rgba`/`hsl` and `calc` expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the Sass documentation for [`color.mix()`/`mix()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color/#mix):

> Returns a color that’s a mixture of `$color1` and `$color2`.

You could consider the [`color-mix()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix). MDN describes it as:

> The `color-mix()` functional notation takes two [`<color>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) values and returns the result of mixing them in a given colorspace by a given amount.

Thus I would determine that `color-mix()` would be the closest native-CSS implementation of Sass's `color.mix()`/`mix()`.

Comment: This is promising! Do you know if `color-mix` is functionally equivalent to `mix` and mixes colors in exactly the same way?

Comment: I don't know if `color-mix` is functionally equivalent to `mix`.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. I followed up and asked at https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/3188. Please edit your answer and include their answer when available!